# AWK is throwing an error "unexpected newline or end of string"

Tags: bash, awk

My Bash script:

```
declare -a lang=('english' 'spainsh')
sms="Free msg: Due to upgrades on apps you’ll need a new version by yyyy/mm/dd to app running. Visit a store or go to"
    url="google.com/UA2392 to upgrade your app." 

awk '{print $1 "," '${servicegrade[0]}' "," '${lang[1]}' ",,," '$sms' "," '$url'}' inputfile.csv > inputfile.txt
```

ERROR:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {print $1 "," 267 "," en ",,," Free
awk: cmd. line:1:                                    ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

Comment: You have some problem: 1. you have to import your array into awk, , 2. if you question , please put your text file into your question.

Comment: You can import your shell variable via -v : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194100/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-bash-array-as-a-variable-to-awk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is directly related to the way that you are quoting (or more accurately, not quoting) your `awk` command line and the interpolated shell variables. (Both for the shell and for `awk`.)

You have this:

> ```
> awk '{print $1 "," '${servicegrade[0]}' "," '${lang[1]}' ",,," '$sms' "," '$url'}' inputfile.csv > inputfile.txt
> ```

Empirically I can see from the error message that `servicegrade=267`, `lang=en`, `sms=Free msg:...`, but `url` is not visible (that's ok) so we'll assume `url=http://example.net`.

The important part is to look at your quotes on the commnd line. Anything inside the 'single quotes' is treated as a single command line. If you abut a single quote against a double quote you're also ok (`echo 'hello'"world"` has a single argument). But as soon as you introduce an unquoted space it becomes a second parameter (`echo 'hello' "world"` is two words, not one). Additionally, none of your variables is quoted so any whitespace in their values will be treated by the shell as a word break.

Let's assume those variables do not contain whitespace, and interpolate them into the command line, as if they were actual values rather than variables:

```
awk '{print $1 "," '267' "," 'en' ",,," 'Free msg:...' "," 'http://example.net'}' inputfile.csv > inputfile.txt
```

Now we'll remove redundant quotes:

```
awk '{print $1 "," 267 "," en ",,," Free msg:..."," http://example.net}' inputfile.csv > inputfile.txt
```

It shouldn't take more than a moment to realise that `awk` is now seeing unquoted strings, which it cannot view as `awk` variables. I suspect that what you really wanted was this:

```
awk '{print $1 ",267,en,,,Free msg:...,http://example.net"}' inputfile.csv > inputfile.txt
```

(possibly with double-quoted arguments if your output is also CSV style).

We can reverse the process easily enough to allow shell variables to be interpolated, but a better approach is to assign those shell variables to `awk` variables and use those:

```
awk -v servicegrade="${servicegrade[0]}" -v lang="${lang[1]}" -v sms="$sms" -v url="$url" '{print $1 "," servicegrade "," lang ",,," sms "," url}' inputfile.csv > inputfile.txt
```

If you decide your output text needs double-quoted parameters, `awk` (well, at least my version of it) understands this sort of structure: `awk '{print $1 "\"" servicegrade "\",\"" lang "\",\"" sms "\",\"" url "\""}'`